# Mongoose query on array returning the complete document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a node.js application where I am trying to query an array using mongoose and I am being returned the complete unfiltered document.
The collection stores a single document with the following Data (This is also the data that I am receiving after executing the query):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c0900f619f89f6943efbfd"
    },
    "milestones": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "5 Friends",
        "description": "refer 5 friends to get 100 GroCash!",
        "isActive": true,
        "reward": 100,
        "condition": 5
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "7 Friends",
        "description": "refer 7 friends to get 100 GroCash!",
        "isActive": true,
        "reward": 150,
        "condition": 7
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "5 Friends",
        "description": "refer 5 friends to get 100 GroCash!",
        "isActive": true,
        "reward": 550,
        "condition": 5
    }],
    "newUserReward": 50,
    "refreeReward": 50
}
```

The query that I am running is : `incentiveModel.find({'milestones.isActive':true,'milestones.condition':5})`
I am expecting it to return me the following data :

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60c0900f619f89f6943efbfd"
        },
        "milestones": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "5 Friends",
            "description": "refer 5 friends to get 100 GroCash!",
            "isActive": true,
            "reward": 100,
            "condition": 5
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "5 Friends",
            "description": "refer 5 friends to get 100 GroCash!",
            "isActive": true,
            "reward": 550,
            "condition": 5
        }],
        "newUserReward": 50,
        "refreeReward": 50
}
```

I have tried `$project` but still no help.
The mongoose schema is :

```
const milestone = new Schema({
    id:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        default:mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        default:''
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        default:''
    },
    isActive:{
        type:Boolean,
        required:true,
        default:false
    },
    condition:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        default:null
    },
    reward:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        default:0
    }
})

export const incentiveScema = new Schema({
    milestones:{
        type:[milestone]
    },
    newUserReward:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    refreeReward:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    }

})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to get data from an array when you do that then mongo DB looks into an array and tries to find the condition, and when it matches it returns the whole array. You can use the aggregation framework and $unwind to turn the array into objects and then it will return the objects matching your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await  incentiveModel.aggregate([
       {
$unwind:'$milestones'
      }
{
    $match:{
       $and:[{'milestones.isActive':true},{'milestones.condition':5}]
    }

    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

refer to this example below..

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xrrby8yN0IS

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could use `aggregate` with `$addFields` on which you can filter out the data. Below is the query for the same. for more reference please go through the this [link](https://www.devsbedevin.net/mongodb-find-findone-with-nested-array-filtering-finally/).

**check the sample [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GfdSscNyoR_)**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "milestones": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$milestones",
          as: "milestones",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$milestones.isActive",
                  true
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$milestones.condition",
                  5
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```